# MPMoviePlayerController gives me a black empty view on BACK button

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have used MPMoviePlayerController to play video in my web view from a live url
but when i pop the view controller so at that time the black screen appears in the view and the navigation bar title changes as it should be.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.url];
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    self.moviePlayer.contentURL = movieURL;

    if (self.moviePlayer)
    {
        [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

        self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

        [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
        [self.moviePlayer.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

        // save the movie player object
        [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
        [self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
        [self.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];

        // Play the movie!
        [self.moviePlayer play];

        [self initializeNavigationController];


    }


}

-(void)initializeNavigationController
{

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] backButtonWithtarget:self action:@selector(Back)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonBack;
}

-(void)Back
{

    [self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self stopLoadingVideoInView];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Live video screen
[image]

After Back button press
[image]

Comment: Can you show screen shot problem after you back?

Comment: i have uploaded both the screen shot

Comment: Can you show code for `stopLoadingVideoInView`? Because I test on my example your code. I work fine, no black screen when back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it finally

In app delgate i created a method to allocate memory to vc again

```
- (void)resetAppToFirstController
{
    UIViewController *obj = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];


    //Create Navigation Controller to Hold View Controller
    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];
   [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
}
```

and on my back button action

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.resetAppToFirstController;
```

This solved my issue it may help some one for MPMoviePlayer

Answer (score 0):

I think you just remove **[self.view removeFromSuperview];** and replace with 
[self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Can you share screen shot of storyboard?

Comment: It is generated programatically

Answer (score 0):

In case you are added youMovieController as sub view of parent view, use this method to remove it.

```
[self.view removeFromSuperView]
```

In case you are pushing viewController via UINavigationController, just call this to go back.

```
[self.navigationCotroller popViewController:animated]
```

In case you are present ViewController, use this to remove it.

```
[self dismissViewController]
```

Answer (score -1):

remove [self.view removeFromSuperview]; and replace with [self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

```
- (void)resetAppToFirstController
{
    UIViewController *obj = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];


    //Create Navigation Controller to Hold View Controller
    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];
   [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
}
```